# How to pass simple parameter in python

Tags: python, variables, parameter-passing, python-3.7, input-parameters

I want to try simple `Python` code `test.py` where I want to pass parameter.

```
import sys    
result = 3 * 3 * <parameter>
print(result)
```

When I run the `Python` code i want to pass value as `3` in input parameter so that i can get result `27` at the end. I can run the python code after passing the value in the parameter. For example i can run the python code like below. Is it possible to do in Python ?

```
 test.py 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were pretty close with the `import sys`. The first command-line argument is in `sys.argv[1]`, as a string.

```
import sys    
result = 3 * 3 * int(sys.argv[1])
print(result)
```

Example:

```
~ > python test.py 3
27
```

Assuming some UNIX-like system, you can run your script as a program (so `./test.py 3`) by making it executable and adding a shebang; to run your script from everywhere (so `test.py 3`), add it to your `$PATH`. Both of these are optional.

[Reference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv)

Comment: thanks and how can i pass string as parameter ?

Comment: It works the same way. `python test.py 3 spam 'eggs foo'` will mean `sys.argv` is `['test.py', '3', 'spam', 'eggs foo']`. Feel free to experiment.

Comment: sorry one more question..for example if i have to pass multiple parameter then how to do that ? For example i have complex code and now i want to pass 3 parameter in different place in my code then does it work in Python ?